# reactjs radio group setting checked attribute based on state

Tags: reactjs

Clicking on the second radio button changes the state which triggers the render event. However, it renders the first radio button as the checked one again even though state.type got changed.

```js
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      type: 1
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    console.log('->> type: ' + this.state.type);//prints the expected value
    return (<div className="my-component">
      <label>type 1</label>
      <input ref="type1Selector" type="radio" name="type" id="type1" 
        onChange={this.changeHandler} checked={this.state.type === 1}/><br/>
      <label>type 2</label>
      <input ref="type2Selector" type="radio" name="type" id="type2" 
        onChange={this.changeHandler} checked={this.state.type === 2}/><br/>
    </div>);
  },
  changeHandler: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = e.currentTarget;
    if(t.id === 'type1') {
      this.setState({type: 1});
    } else {
      this.setState({type: 2});
    }
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell how to get this to work and why react is behaving like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the React docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#potential-issues-with-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons), there are potential issues with checkboxes and radio buttons.

> Be aware that, in an attempt to normalize change handling for checkbox and radio inputs, React uses a click event in place of a change event. For the most part this behaves as expected, except when calling preventDefault in a change handler. preventDefault stops the browser from visually updating the input, even if checked gets toggled. This can be worked around either by removing the call to preventDefault, or putting the toggle of checked in a setTimeout.

So what you want to do is remove the `e.preventDefault()` in your `changeHandler` function.